# Laravel ajax multiple forms submission _token error

Tags: ajax, laravel-5.3

I am new to laravel and can't handle multiple ajax form submission with dynamic dropdown values.

I have a multi step form which submits through ajax. When I submit the form1 using ajax and load new form2, the dynamic dropdown fetching ajax city data on form2 is not working and its showing token mismatch error.

```
<form 1>
    csrf_token()
</form 1>

<form 2>
    csrf_token()
</form 2>

//Ajax 1
    csrf_token()

//Ajax for city data
    csrf_token()
```

Any suggestion would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add data in your ajax request. I hope so it will be work.

```
data: {
    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
     "id": id
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have tokens in all ajax requests